# Assigning an enumerator to an enum type with enumerators of the same value

Tags: c++, variable-assignment, enumeration

Given this enum and assignment:

```
enum Points {point2d = 2, point2w, point3d = 3, point3w};
Points pt3d = point3d;
```

At a breakpoint just past this assignment, the debugger reports that pt3d has the value point2w. Why not point3d, as assigned?

Comment: Because both have the value `3`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `enum` is just a way to set fancy, compile time type safe names for enums. What happens is that each of your enum values get assigned a numerical integer value:

```
enum Points
{
  // Explicitly map point2d to value 2.
  point2d = 2,

  // Let point2w get an automatic mapping - will be previous + 1 = 3.
  point2w,

  // Explicitly map pint3d to value 3.
  point3d = 3,

  // Let point3w get an automatic mapping - will be previous + 1 = 4.
  point3w
}
```

So to the runtime, the statement `Points pt3d = point3d` is the same as `Points pt3d = 3`. When displaying, the debugger simply takes the first enum value mapped againts 3, which is `point2w`.

Answer (score 2):

```
enum Points {point2d = 2, point2w, point3d = 3, point3w};
Points pt3d = point3d;
```

When you don't set a value like for `point2w`, it continue to increment, then since `point2d = 2`, `point2w` will be equal to 3 like `point3d`. `point3w` will be equal to 4 because `point3d` is set to 3.

You should read [this about enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dzy4k6e%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Hope that helps you.